# How to make view visible in one component from clicking a button from another component?

Tags: react-native

i have two components
Component A has one button by default that is hidden and another component
B which has search button
how to make button in component A visible when i click button in component B
i m importing component B in A 
How to achieve above mention ?

Answer (score 0):

When you activate a button, there are many ways to float other components.

You can change the status value to float it, 
OR you can pass the value through the key value to receive the data and execute the button,
 as shown in the example below.

example.js

```js
      <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.getItems()}
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              style={styles.btn}
              textStyle={styles.txt}
            >Get Products ({productList.length})</TouchableOpacity>
            {
              productList.map((product, i) => {
                return (
                  <View key={i} style={{
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                  }}>
                    <Text style={{
                      marginTop: 20,
                      fontSize: 12,
                      color: 'black',
                      minHeight: 100,
                      alignSelf: 'center',
                      paddingHorizontal: 20,
                    }} >{JSON.stringify(product)}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => this.buyItem(product.productId)}
                      activeOpacity={0.5}
                      style={styles.btn}
                      textStyle={styles.txt}
                    >Buy Above Product</TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                );
              })
            }
```